dotNET minimal API getting 404 not found on a secure endpoint
I am trying to implement a rest api using the dotNET framework. I am experiencing a problem with the "/secure" endpoint, getting 404 as a response message whether I login or not.
If I don't use IdentityUser class and if I use the /login endpoint which is commented out in the code, the "/secure" endpoint works correctly, getting 401 if not logged in and 200 after logged in.
Also, can you explain me if i need to use builder.Services.AddControllers()?
Thank you all!
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using ApiLogin;
using ApiLogin.Api;
using ApiLogin.Database;
using ApiLogin.Handlers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));

// // Register Identity services
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

//                  Id,  Version, Path
var api = new Api("api-v0", "v0", "/v0");

// Swagger
// builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen((options) => {
    options.SwaggerDoc(api.Id, new() { Title = api.Id, Version = api.Version });
});

// Authentication
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YourSuperSecretKeyThatIsAtLeast32BytesLong!");
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
        };
    });


builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UsePathBase("/api");


// Authentication
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Endpoint
var endpoint = app.MapGroup(api.Path).WithGroupName(api.Id);
// ApiV0.MapEndpoints(endpoint);

var todoItems = endpoint.MapGroup("todoitems").WithTags("ToDoItems");
_ = todoItems.MapGet("/", ListTodos.Handle);


// Authentication
// Endpoint definition
// endpoint.MapPost("/login", (LoginModel model) => {

//     if (model.Username == "testuser" && model.Password == "Password123!") {
//         var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
//         var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
//             Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username) }),
//             Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
//             SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
//         };
//         var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
//         var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
//         return TypedResults.Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
//     }
//     return Results.Unauthorized();
// });


endpoint.MapPost("/register", async (RegisterModel model, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager) => {
    var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email };
    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded) {
        return TypedResults.Ok();
    }
    return Results.BadRequest(result.Errors);
});


endpoint.MapPost("/login", async (LoginModel model, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager) => {
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
    if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password)) {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName!)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        return TypedResults.Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
    }
    return Results.Unauthorized();
});


endpoint.MapGet("/secure", [Authorize] () => "This is a secure endpoint");


// Swagger UI
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    _ = app.UseSwagger();
    _ = app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint($"{api.Id}/swagger.yaml", api.Id);
    });
}

await app.RunAsync();


Application Context
using ApiLogin.Database.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ApiLogin.Database;

public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser> {

    public DbSet<Todo> Todos => Set<Todo>();

    public ApplicationContext() { }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }

}




I am trying to implement a rest api using the dotNET framework. I am
experiencing a problem with the "/secure" endpoint, getting 404 as a
response message whether I login or not.

Based on your shared code snippet and description, I was trying to troubleshoot your scenario.
According to my investigation the issue you're facing might be due to the way you mapped endpoints also the path base is being set.
Because, once the endpoint is defined as app.MapGroup("/api/v0"). This ensures that all endpoints within this group will be prefixed with /api/v0, so you no longer need app.UsePathBase("/api"); and this is hte primary reason you are getting 404.
Using them together causing the actual paths to be different from what was expected. This could lead to 404 errors because the routes did not match the expected endpoints.
Here is the complete steps how I have implemented your code:
In order to simulate your scenario, I have used InMemoryUserStore and InMemoryRoleStore to simulate Identity user without creating DbContext instnace. Rest of the code I tried to keep as yours.
Program.cs: before build:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
})
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();




var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YourSuperSecretKeyThatIsAtLeast32BytesLong!");
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();



var app = builder.Build();

Middleware Uses After Build:
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//I am Using Demo user setup
var userStore = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>();
var roleStore = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>>();
var demoUser = new IdentityUser { UserName = "demoUser", Email = "demo@example.com" };
var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
demoUser.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(demoUser, "Password123!");

await userStore.CreateAsync(demoUser, default);

//Here I am setting endpoint definitions
var endpoint = app.MapGroup("/api/v0").WithGroupName("ApiV0");



endpoint.MapPost("/register", async (RegisterModel model) =>
{
    // Skiping registration in demo mode
    return TypedResults.Ok("Registration is not required in demo mode.");
});

endpoint.MapPost("/login", async (LoginModel model) =>
{
    if (model.Username == demoUser.UserName && model.Password == "Password123!")
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, demoUser.UserName!)
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        return TypedResults.Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
    }
    return Results.Unauthorized();
});

//endpoint.MapGet("/secure", [Authorize] () => "This is a secure endpoint");

endpoint.MapGet("/secure", [Authorize] (HttpContext context) => {
    var headers = context.Request.Headers;
    var authHeader = headers["Authorization"].ToString();
    var token = authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? authHeader.Substring(7) : authHeader;

    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var customHeaderValue))
    {
        return Results.Ok($"This is a secure endpoint. Reqeust-Header: {customHeaderValue}");
    }
    else
    {
        return Results.BadRequest("Bearer token is missing");
    }
});



await app.RunAsync();

Output:





Note: Please refer to this official document, for additional reference.

I have just fixed the issue, now it also work with application context. However, if I use:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
instead of:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; }) 
It doesn't work and I only get 404 on /secure endpoint. Can you explain me why? Thank you

Well, default authentication scheme to JWT Bearer authentication. When used alone, it doesn't specify how to handle authentication and challenge actions. So when the challenge scheme is not set, the application may not correctly identify that it should use JWT Bearer for handling authorization challenges. This misconfiguration can result in the framework not correctly mapping the /secure endpoint, leading to a 404 error. Essentially, the endpoint may not recognize the authorization requirement properly.
